# Android MaterialAlertDialog without extending Theme.MaterialComponent

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog, material-components-android, material-components

I'm extending from 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar' and I don't want to switch my AppTheme to MaterialDesign

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context, R.style.MaterialDialog)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, _ -> dialog.dismiss() }
            .show()
```

```
<style name="MaterialDialog" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorSurface">#ffffff</item>
    </style>
```

**Expcted**

[image: What I expected:]

**Result:**

[image: What I got:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't move to a Material Components Theme you should use a [Bridge theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#bridge-themes-bridge-themes). Something like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge">
    <item name="colorSurface">#ffffff</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Then in your code just use:

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
   .setCancelable(false)
   ...
```

If you want to override the colors only for the dialog just use:

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context,R.style.MaterialDialog)
   .setCancelable(false)
   ...
```

with:

```
  <style name="MaterialDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/AlertDialogOverlay</item>
  </style>  


  <style name="AlertDialogOverlay">
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/....</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/.....</item>
    ....
  </style>
```

Comment: Hi , Can we set the margin to `MaterialDialog`?